# Inserting multiple counts into a second mySQL table

Tags: mysql, replace, insert, count

I must have looked at over a hundred posts on this and none have hit close enough where I can figure this out.  I have 2 tables – a ‘housing’ table and a ‘summary’ table.   I need to count the number of units in the ‘housing’ table that, 
1.) have a Status of ‘Active’ and a Class of ‘Rental’, and 
2.) have a Status of ‘Active’ and a Class of ‘Sale’ 
...in each of several buildings, and then insert the counts next to the building names in the ‘summary’ table:

‘housing’ table

```
Building                Unit No.    Status  Class     
----------             ----------    -------    ------
10 South Hampton            1107    Active  Rental
1 Nile Place                 712    Active  Sale
Forsythe Tower N            203N    Closed  Sale
Forsythe Tower S            117S    Active  Rental
Hickory Commons              315    Closed  Sale
10 South Hampton             202    Active  Sale
1 Nile Place                 311    Active  Rental
Forsythe Tower N            619N    Active  Rental
Forsythe Tower N            408N    Active  Sale
Hickory Commons             202     Closed  Sale
10 South Hampton            1420    Closed  Rental
1 Nile Place                 507    Active  Rental
Forsythe Tower N            810N    Active  Sale
Forsythe Tower S            716S    Active  Sale
Hickory Commons              319    Active  Rental
```

‘summary’ table

```
Building               Sales     Rentals    Col3    Col4    Col5
----------            ------     -------    ------  -----   ------
1 Nile Place               1      2
10 South Hampton           1      1
Forsythe Tower N           2      1
Forsythe Tower S           1      1
Hickory Commons            0      1
```

I got this working for a single count (Sales):

```
REPLACE summary (Building, Sales) 
SELECT   Building,
COUNT(*) FROM housing WHERE Status='Active' AND class ='Sales',
GROUP BY Building
```

Then I felt dangerous and found the snipet below, which looked great but didn’t work for both 

```
REPLACE summary (Sales, Rentals)
SELECT  Building,
        SUM(Class ='Sales' AND Status='Active') Sales,
        SUM(Class='Rentals' AND Status='Active') Rentals
FROM summary
GROUP BY Building
```

I'm really just getting my feet wet in this aspect of mySQL so suggestions on how to crack this would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested my syntax here, but this is the general idea:

```
select Building,
sum(case when Class='Sales' and Status='Active' then 1 else 0 end) Sales,
sum(case when Class='Rentals' and Status='Active' then 1 else 0 end) Rentals
from summary
group by Building
```

Answer (score 0):

ALTER table summary ADD Counts VARCHAR(60) AFTER Building;

SELECT Count(DISTINCT housing.Status)

FROM housing h, summary s

WHERE Status ='Active' AND (Class ='Sales' OR Class ='Rental')

JOIN  summary

ON    s.Building = h.Building;